# Navigation bar not showing in modal view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation

I am going through the Scrumdinger tutorial from Apple. I am adding the code and the preview, as you can see something is wrong with the navigation toolbar. The title is also missing. Checked on Simulator and device, also not working.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```swift
#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        Text("Some Text")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                DetailEditView()
                    .navigationTitle("Meeting")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            Button("Add", action: {})
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting it in wrong order, it should be:

```swift
Text("Some Text")
    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
        NavigationStack { //<- Here
            DetailEditView()
                .navigationTitle("Meeting")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button("Add", action: {})
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic please? I was following Apple's tutorial, they did it like I did. Thanks

P.S. in the app the root view is wrapped in a NavigationStack, as far as I understand that should be enough, no?

Comment: Can you share the tutorial? From my perspective, it's simply from a different view hierarchy. If you declare `NavigationStack` from the outer `Text`, it's for the parent View. It cannot apply to the presenting one. I think the logic behind scene is the same like UIKit.

Comment: Actually, it's not perfect, if you want to push to another view in `DetailEditView`. Move all those navigation and toolBar in its declaration, and split it from the parent. Just a single `.sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) { DetailEditView() }`